# How to select data with minimum time interval between results

Tags: influxdb

I am not sure how to best ask this question.. I am looking to select data but with a minimum time interval between the results. For example:

This measurement:

```
time                    field     
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z    12            
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z    1             
2015-08-18T00:06:00Z    11           
2015-08-18T00:06:00Z    3            
2015-08-18T05:54:00Z    2             
2015-08-18T06:00:00Z    1             
2015-08-18T06:06:00Z    8
2015-08-18T06:12:00Z    7
```

This Query:

`select sum(*) from measurement where field > 0` would return the sum of all of the rows. I would like to be able to specify a minimum interval between results and only match on the first row in a set of closely timed rows. Ex. 8 minute minimum interval would only match these rows (and result in a sum of 22):

```
time                    field     
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z    12                    
2015-08-18T05:54:00Z    2                     
2015-08-18T06:06:00Z    8
```

Is there a way to get my expected output from influxdb?

The only alternative I can think of is to just return all of the rows without the sum() aggregate function then loop through the results and do lots of time comparisons or date math in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not with InfluxQL.
InfluxQL has a function `elapsed` which returns the time elapsed between consecutive datapoints https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/functions/#elapsed
That's possibly the only function that has something to do with time but I can't think of a way to apply it for what you need.

You may have better luck with the `window` function of Flux https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/query-data/guides/window-aggregate/
I'm not familiar enough to say how, if at all possible.

Doing it in your application may be the way to go.